# An Experiment involving macrosopic quantum superposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

The field produced by a charged macroscopic body prepared in a superposition of different position eigenstates is also expected to be in a superposition, for if not, the field strength's give away the information about the position of the charged macroscopic body, destroying the superposition. Therefore the above system has to be described by a state, which is not decomposable as a simple direct product of the states of the fields and the charged macroscopic body respectively. That is, we get an entangled state, in the absence of any other external noise. 
Are there any actual experiments done exploring the kind of situation mentioned above? Any reference to original literature would be appreciated.